# Ksysguard give error The file /home/mahesh/.kde/share/apps/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd does not contain valid XML

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I've Dell Inspiron 1525 with Kubuntu 14.04. Recently when I checked for update Muon Update Manager told me that few updates are available so I updated it but now when I use Ksysyguard gives error "The file /home/mahesh/.kde/share/apps/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd does not contain valid XML."
  Any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I search KDE's official  site http://www.kde.org/ .Where I searched for KSysguard. And at the following link; I found my answer by renaming .kde folder in my Home folder to .kde[4] https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=123599&p=325151#p32515

Answer (score 10):

Since the change to KDE5 the solution has changed. My system monitor got borked because cache cleaning and rebooting too fast.

So because I don't have enough reputation to up-vote or comment here's Pablo's solution revised.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd /home/[youruser]/.local/share/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd
```

You may also need to copy the CPU usage tab as well (which I did)

```
sudo cp /usr/share/ksysguard/SystemLoad2.sgrd /home/[youruser]/.local/share/ksysguard/SystemLoad2.sgrd
```

And you may also need to click the 'Import Tab From File...' and point to the .local directory to select one or more of the files.

Comment: This has solved the problem for me.

Comment: No need to use `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
cp /usr/share/apps/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd /home/YOUR_USER/.kde4/share/apps/ksysguard/ProcessTable.sgrd
```